# Creating sample data for existing UI in Blend?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, expression-blend, sample-data

I'm trying to connect sample data for a WP8 app in Blend.

All tutorials seem to build their UI around sample data. I have a UI already and just want to populate with sample data.
If I drag my sample data to a UI control, it's replaced by a repeater connected to the sample data instead.

How do I add sample data from Blend without altering the ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic happens with modifier keys on drag.
**SHIFT**-drag is what I was looking for. Add **CTRL** if you only want to bind against the first item i the sample data.

[This excellent article](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/11/26/blend-bits-18-sample-data.aspx) provides screenshots.